# Overloading the commit/save functions

Tags: python, django

I'm developing a system with a client side and server side database. The problem here concerns synchronisation. Currently my server-side application will generate a hash code based on a models dictionary items, this is computed each time a request is made for data by the client. If the client's code does not match the servers one then it will be sent the data from the server and update its has code with the new server one which is also sent by the server.

Generating the code by hashing all the models items is quite expensive and the problem gets a lot worse with greater amounts of data.

I was wondering if instead I could have the server generate a random code and the overload Model.models save and commit functions so they expire the code when anything hits the database.

This scenario leads me to two questions ...is this in fact possible? And...  How would I overload the operators so that the default logic is still run after my code has generated a new random token.

Comment: Would [signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/) do what you want?

Comment: Yes this is a good suggestion... thank you